# How can I start animation when mediaplayer is running. If mediaplayer is not runnning, animation also will not run

Tags: android

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncheck);
final MediaPlayer true_answer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 

R.raw.answer_is_true);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    true_answer.start();
                    if (true_answer.isPlaying()){//doesn't work
                        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
                        AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground()Q;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
                    AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)image.getBackground();
                    animation.stop();
                }
            });
```

Am I right with the function isRunning? or I should add while. I can not solve this problem. Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your activity or fragment must implement **Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener**

and **mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);** you can register this.

you will get on complete callback where you can stop media.

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        animation.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Add complete activity code where you are doing all the stuffs.